# How can I get mossy cobblestone on survival in mcpe?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Ok. I was playing mcpe and I noticed that mossy cobblestone isn't in the crafting table. And I wanted to make a house that looks old. So if its possible to get mossy cobblestone without mods, how can I get it on survival? If it is possible can somebody please leave a step by step guide. Thank you.

Comment: Mossy cobble isn't craftable in the regular version either.  I suspect (but can't be sure) that it's the same process: find a dungeon, if they exist.

Comment: Ahh. Well that stinks

Answer (score 4):

In version 1.8 for the PC and in Pocket Edition 0.9.5, you can craft mossy cobblestone from cobblestone and vines like so:

[image: Mossy cobblestone recipe: one cobblestone and one vine, shapeless]

---

In earlier versions, mossy cobblestone isn't craftable.

It's only generated around dungeons, so you must gather it by finding dungeons, disabling the spawner, and mining the mossy cobblestone with a stone pick or better.

There are mods for these earlier PC versions that add crafting recipes for it (Forestry in particular I'm thinking of).

Comment: PC 1.8 and PE 0.9.5 have changed this, now see John's answer.

Comment: @ZAD-Man Thanks for the reminder. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

First,cut some vines with shears and get some cobblestone. Then you can craft mossy cobblestone,in Minecraft PE it is actually called Moss Stone. Also,you can get it from dungeons.

Comment: As reference: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Moss_Stone

Answer (score -6):

You can make it yourself by putting cobblestone in or near water

Comment: I highly disagree.

Comment: HOW!!!!!!????!!!!